# Working with dates in Coldfusion

Tags: date, coldfusion

I am storing two dates start/end date incremented by weeks, so for example I would have a start date of 05/31/2012 which would end four weeks later on 06/28/2012.

What I need to figure out is the "current week" for any given day.  I would like to output as the week number and not a date. So if today were 06/08/2012 and my start/end date were 05/31/2012, the "current week" would be 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want to use the dateDiff() function.  Basically, you can drop your first date and second date in and count the difference in weeks.

```
// Here's the function
dateDiff("datepart", "date1", "date2")

// Here are your datepart options
yyyy: Years
q: Quarters
m: Months
y: Days of year (same as d)
d: Days
w: Weekdays (same as ww)
ww: Weeks
h: Hours
n: Minutes
s: Seconds

// Here's your code:
StartOfMonth = "05/31/2012"; // date part 1 // pseudocode
Now = now(); // date part 2
WeeksDifference = DateDiff("ww", StartOfMonth, Now);
```

Comment: Yep, dateDiff is the ticket. RE *if today was 06/08/2012 ..."current week" = 2* Just a note for future readers, to get that result you need to use `DateDiff("ww", StartOfMonth, Now) +1`. Reason is `DateDiff` returns the difference in *whole* weeks. So for 06/08/2012, it actually returns `1`, not `2`.